# Are setState callbacks NOT invoked then the update itself is overridden by a different update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a slider that invokes a function when `onChange` is called.
The function changes an 'expensive' state that many components depend on, and calls additional state dependent functions in it's callback block.

I assume that due to asynchronous nature of setState is it possible that 
dragging the slider can result in seemingly simultaneous setState updates, such that only one of the update is accepted.

If that is the case, can I guarantee that only the callback of the accepted newState is invoked? It is important that the callback matches the current state.

Edit: An example

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
     v: 0,
     w: 0
   };
  }

  onChange = v => {
   this.setState(
    () => {
     return { v: v };
    },
    () => {
     this.stateDependentFunction();
    }
   );
  };

  stateDependentFunction = () => {
   let v = this.state.v;
   this.setState({ w: 5 * v + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
     <div style={{ width: "80%", marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: "auto"}}>
      <Slider
       disabled={false}
       min={0}
       max={1000}
       defaultValue={0}
       onChange={this.onChange}
      />
      Value: {this.state.v} <br />
      Value2: {this.state.w}
    </div>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: If it is triggered as you slide it, then you'll do multiple updates (which will be inefficient if the state change is expensive, as you've said). If you want to avoid that, you'll have to find a way to capture when they've stopped sliding for good, e.g. a "mouse up" event on the slider

Comment: You mean the `this.setState(( prevState ) => ...)`? Having a minimal code example would be helpful, only to see what your current logic is, and if something can be altered...

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that due to asynchronous nature of setState is it possible that dragging the slider can result in seemingly simultaneous setState updates, such that only one of the update is accepted.

All state updates will be accepted even if they have no visible effect, because they are triggered asynchronously. A way to not cause excessive amount of state updates is to debounce event listener, e.g. with Lodash `debounce`.

`stateDependentFunction` doesn't need to be executed after previous `setState` has ended, this will result in 2 state updates, while this could be handled with single update. [Updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) allows to queue state updates. `stateDependentFunction` is an antipattern, `this.state` shouldn't be used with `setState` because this may result in race conditions, this is what updater function is for.

It can be:

```
  onChange = debounce(v => {
   this.setState({ v }); // doesn't need updater function
   this.stateDependentFunction();
  }, 50);

  stateDependentFunction = () => {
   this.setState(({ v }) => ({ w: 5 * v + 1 })); // needs updater function
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't knew about debounce.

But shouldn't be the `stateDependentFunction` be in the callback block of the first `setState`? Otherwise the last call to `onChange` might update `w` with the previous `v` value.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The purpose of updater function is to address this problem, as the answer explains. Check the manual I've linked.

Comment: The manual says "Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date.". I also know that it waits for other `setState`'s with updater functions - https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/824309659775467527.
But does it mean that the updater function also waits for pending `setState`'s (without updater functions) to finish?

Comment: Yes, it chains `setState` updates and then does actual state update.